# PublishSubject doOnSubscribe not called

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I have a PublishSubject with a registered `doOnSubscribe` and `doOnUnsubscribe` actions. Both actions are not called, if a subscription is done.

```
private PublishSubject<Long> publishSubject;
private Subscription subscription;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     
    publishSubject = PublishSubject.create();
    publishSubject.doOnSubscribe(new Action0() {
        @Override
        public void call() {
            Log.d("SUBJECT", "Someone subscribed.");
        }
    });
    publishSubject.doOnUnsubscribe(new Action0() {
        @Override
        public void call() {
            Log.d("SUBJECT", "Someone UNsubscribed.");
        }
    });

    Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS).subscribe(new Action1<Long>() {
        @Override
        public void call(final Long tick) {
            publishSubject.onNext(tick);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    subscription = publishSubject.subscribe(new Action1<Long>() {
        @Override
        public void call(final Long aLong) {
            Log.d("SUBJECT", "Got tick " + aLong);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

But in my logcat, I only get the `"Got tick "` message and no `"Someone subscribed"`.

```
07-25 17:57:34.110 8753-8965/com.example.plinzen.myapplication I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
07-25 17:57:34.954 8753-8964/com.example.plinzen.myapplication D/SUBJECT: Got tick 0
07-25 17:57:35.950 8753-8964/com.example.plinzen.myapplication D/SUBJECT: Got tick 1
07-25 17:57:36.950 8753-8964/com.example.plinzen.myapplication D/SUBJECT: Got tick 2
07-25 17:57:37.950 8753-8964/com.example.plinzen.myapplication D/SUBJECT: Got tick 3
07-25 17:57:38.949 8753-8964/com.example.plinzen.myapplication D/SUBJECT: Got tick 4
07-25 17:57:39.950 8753-8964/com.example.plinzen.myapplication D/SUBJECT: Got tick 5
```

Any idea, why these actions are not called, when subscribing is in `onResume()` and unsubscribing is in `onPause()`? Do I misunderstand the Subject topic?

Comment: explain *Both actions are not called, if a subscription is done*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't break the chain:

```
private Observable<Long> publishedObservable;

[...]

PublishSubject<Long> publishSubject = PublishSubject.create();
publishedObservable = publishSubject.doOnSubscribe(new Action0() {
    @Override
    public void call() {
        Log.d("SUBJECT", "Someone subscribed.");
    }
}).doOnUnsubscribe(new Action0() {
    @Override
    public void call() {
        Log.d("SUBJECT", "Someone UNsubscribed.");
    }
});
```

And in the other methods use `publishedObservable`.

See, in your code you create two new Observables, but you throw them away directly; the `.doFooBar` methods do not modify an Observable, they create a new one that implements the desired behavior.